# How can one use the "Guest Option" in Rankade?

Tags: online, game-accessories

Just discovered [Rankade](https://rankade.com) (in a comment here somewhere) and still learning the ropes...

I've read about [the Guest option in the FAQ](https://rankade.com/frequently-asked-question/3/what-does-the-guest-option-mean/43) but can't find a way to add one to a match...
Is it a particular type of ghost player? 
What if the guest finally end up being a regular member? Can he be upgraded like a ghost player?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer directly from the Rankade team:

> You can add a new player during the faction step. Just type their email, and 
>   then choose if you want them to be a 'member' or a 'guest'. Guest user 
>   cannot access group data and is not listed in the rankings.
>   You can 'upgrade' a guest by reinserting them in another match and calling 
>   him 'member'. Ghosts are users that are not linked to an email address. 
>   They're managed by the group's admin.
>   A Guest user is not listed in the rankings, but he has his (hidden) ranking, indeed. So, yes, the guest "*changes the ranks even if he isn't ranked himself*" [it's a quote from the question], and you have to insert the actual order (ree calculations depend on all standings, so you need to correctly enter the full results, not just the winner).
>   We recommend the use of actual users, because some features (matchup 
>   stats and more) are not available for guest and ghosts.